# trying to set value in promise .then returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular 1.5, and used to rely on `$scope` for doing something like this, where I would bind the return value of a promise to the scope. I'm inside a service, and am trying to return data via a promise, and I want that data to then be exposed via this service. however, the data, `mockData` is undefined:

```
let mockData;
  function getWidgets() {
    return $http.get(`${RuntimeConfig.DEV_API_URL}/widgets`, { cache: widgetsCache })
  }
  getWidgets().then(function(data) {
    mockData = data.data;
  })
  console.log(mockData); //undefined.
```

return value of this service:

```
    return {
    mockData
  };
```

my previous way to solve this would have been by declaring `$scope.mockData`, but I can't do that because a) it's an antipattern now b) i'm in a service. what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Its undefined as before that `getWigets()` promise is returned. Either resolve the promise before stateChange of wait for it to resolve in the controller

Comment: The `getWidgets()` function returns a promise, which (probably) means that it's asynchronous. The function passed to `.then()` will run when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mockData will be `undefined` since it get's returned even before your GET request finish. One way to handle this is to return the promise from the service and handle the promise resolution in let's say controller.

Answer (score 0):

Inject $q dependency in your code.

```
 function getWidgets() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   $http.get(`${RuntimeConfig.DEV_API_URL}/widgets`, { cache: widgetsCache })

   return deferred.promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting mockData to be an array or an object rather than a primitive